# When I press Alt + ) my terminal/console is opening on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, macos, android-studio

When I press alt + ) the terminal of Android Studio is opening and I can't write '}' in my code :( 
But when I'm in the terminal I can write '}'.

I don't understand what the problem is.

When I close the window of the terminal, it's same thing :(

Have you got an idea ?

(On MacOsX)

(Sorry about my english)

Thanks ;)

Comment: check your preferences for existing keyboard shortcuts. see also http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-tips.html#KeyCommands

Comment: WT... :D I delete shortcut to open terminal.. That was Alt + - . And now is working :)

Comment: So strange because I never put any configuration here :O
Thank you very very very much :)